# Auto fill nonexistent data in Highstock's chart

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/v5yEG/5/

```
xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e){
                    this.update({max: e.dataMax})
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to auto fill all existed data to the edges of axis.

As you see, the 'update' method of xAxis doesn't works.

So, this picture will explain all:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1NnI0VFDVA3Yzh5N01neWpRRkU/edit?pli=1

Comment: You can't "autofill" data that doesn't exist.  Your input has no data for the period you want to fill.  Highcharts can't just draw a line across nodata.  If you want to fill that you need to pre-process your input such that you interpolate across the missing data values (which may not be a good idea for as much data as you are missing and the variability of the data you have).

Comment: Yes, i know that it can't be automatically. So i need an issue that can adjust the xAxis accordingly existed data

Comment: Have you tried to use connectNulls ? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.connectNulls

Comment: @SebastianBochan This one didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If I udnerstand correctly, you can do something along the lines of this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KFdMy/0/

```
this.series[1].addPoint([len0,last1]);
```

It's unclear what y value you want the data to have, or how the end of your chart is determined, but perhaps that will help.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, this is really unclear. This one works, but this is not an issue.